# Performance penalty using 'auto' keyword in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2010, c++11

Using the new `auto` keyword has degraded my code execution times. I narrowed the problem to the following simple code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void func1(map<int, vector<deque<float>>>& m)
{
    vector<deque<float>>& v = m[1];
}

void func2(map<int, vector<deque<float>>>& m)
{
    auto v = m[1];
}

void main () {

    map<int, vector<deque<float>>> m;
    m[1].push_back(deque<float>(1000,1));

    clock_t begin=clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) func1(m);
    cout << "100000 x func1: " << (((double)(clock() - begin))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " sec." << endl;

    begin=clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) func2(m);
    cout << "100000 x func2: " << (((double)(clock() - begin))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " sec." << endl;

}
```

The output I get on my i7 / Win7 machine (Release mode; VS2010) is:

```
100000 x func1: 0.001 sec.
100000 x func2: 3.484 sec.
```

Can anyone explain why using `auto` results in such a different execution times?

Obviously, there is a simple workaround, i.e., stop using `auto` altogether, but I hope there is a better way to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are copying the vector to `v`.

Try this instead to create a reference

```
auto& v = ...
```

Comment: Damn, you have to be really fast to answer those questions. ;-)

Comment: I thought (but I guess I was wrong) that auto uses the return type of the function. The return type of operator[] is reference so why do we need to add the extra '&' ?

Comment: @MDman: `auto` removes top-level cv and reference, it "decays" the deduced type.

Comment: @MDman: Also, how would you ever be able to create a copy if the deduced type was always exactly the type of the expression? :) I think that was one of the rationales for having `auto` behave this way.

Answer (score 13):

As Bo said, you have to use `auto&` instead of `auto` (Note, that there is also `auto*` for other cases). Here is an updated version of your code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

typedef map<int, vector<deque<float>>> FooType; // this should have a meaningful name

void func1(FooType& m)
{
    vector<deque<float>>& v = m[1];
}

void func2(FooType& m)
{
    auto v = m[1];
}

void func3(FooType& m)
{
    auto& v = m[1];
}

void measure_time(std::function<void(FooType&)> func, FooType& m)
{
    clock_t begin=clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) func(m);
    cout << "100000 x func: " << (((double)(clock() - begin))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " sec." << endl;
}

void main()
{
    FooType m;
    m[1].push_back(deque<float>(1000,1));

    measure_time(func1, m);
    measure_time(func2, m);
    measure_time(func3, m);
}
```

On my computer, it gives the following output:

```
100000 x func: 0 sec.
100000 x func: 3.136 sec.
100000 x func: 0 sec.
```